# Is It possible to Keep a view Beside actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hello guys i have a requirement where I need to move the action bar to little left and place a view  on button click and again on button click i need to hide view beside action bar and make action bar to full width [image: SOme thing like this]

I am using custom action bar in my activity

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_reader);
```

my custom view

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_sidebar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_back"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/search_reader"
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:clickable="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible to move action bar, I serched a lot but didnt find any thing related to it.  Is that possible? if yes how?

Comment: just use YourView.setVisiBility(View.GONE);

Comment: i didnt yet keep the view. i need to know how to keep that view beside action bar

Comment: post your custome view xml

Comment: added my custom view

Comment: now you click on search imageview right?

Comment: nope on the navigation menu icon image view

Comment: which view you are putting beside action bar?

Comment: that whole red part is 1 image View

Comment: use toolbar and placed your custom layout beside toolbar

Comment: @Redman Can you be a bit clearer. I guess you want a custom view to appear to the right of the actionBar on a button click and disappear later on a button click? Edit : Also post the main layout file which consists the toolbar view.

Comment: i don't have a toolbar,i am using a custom actionbar as i wrote in above code